# Get the application's path

Tags: language-agnostic, path

I've recently searched how I could get the application's directory in Java. I've finally found the answer but I've needed surprisingly long because searching for such a generic term isn't easy. I think it would be a good idea to compile a list of how to achieve this in multiple languages.

Feel free to up/downvote if you (don't) like the idea and **please contribute** if you like it.

### Clarification:

There's a fine distinction between the *directory that contains the executable file* and the *current working directory* (given by `pwd` under Unix). I was originally interested in the former but feel free to post methods for determining the latter as well (clarifying which one you mean).

Comment: What path do you mean? The current working directory, or the directory in which the executable code resides?

Answer (score 59):

In **Java** the calls

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

and

```
new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

return the current working directory.

The call to

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

returns the path to the JAR file containing the current class, or the CLASSPATH element (path) that yielded the current class if you're running directly from the filesystem.

Example:

1. Your application is located at

   ```
    C:\MyJar.jar
   ```
2. Open the shell (cmd.exe) and `cd` to C:\test\subdirectory.
3. Start the application using the command `java -jar C:\MyJar.jar`.
4. The first two calls return 'C:\test\subdirectory'; the third call returns 'C:\MyJar.jar'.

When running from a filesystem rather than a JAR file, the result will be the path to the root of the generated class files, for instance

```
c:\eclipse\workspaces\YourProject\bin\
```

The path does not include the package directories for the generated class files.

A complete example to get the application directory without .jar file name, or the corresponding path to the class files if running directly from the filesystem (e.g. when debugging):

```
String applicationDir = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(); 

if (applicationDir.endsWith(".jar"))
{
    applicationDir = new File(applicationDir).getParent();
}
// else we already have the correct answer
```

Comment: Was looking for a way to put read-only files into the same package as the java classes... getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()  worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis That's exactly what `Class.getResource()` is for.

Answer (score 22):

In **.NET (C#, VB, …)**, you can query the current `Assembly` instance for its `Location`. However, this has the executable's file name appended. The following code sanitizes the path (`using System.IO` and `using System.Reflection`):

```
Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Alternatively, you can use the information provided by `AppDomain` to search for referenced assemblies:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

VB allows another shortcut via the `My` namespace:

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Comment: You can also use Application.StartupPath for some programs. It won't work for ASP.NET, though.

Comment: Actually its, Application.ExecutablePath

Answer (score 9):

In **Windows**, use the WinAPI function [GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx).  Pass in NULL for the module handle to get the path for the current module.

Answer (score 7):

**Python**

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

That gets the path of the current module.

Answer (score 5):

**Objective-C Cocoa** (Mac OS X, I don't know for iPhone specificities):

```
NSString * applicationPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

Comment: In my Mac OSX app, I was looking for the actual path to the executable file (for inclusion in a plist) and used this: NSString *executablePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath]; - there's also an 'executableURL' version to return an URL instead of a string

Answer (score 4):

In **Java**, there are two ways to find the application's path. One is to employ `System.getProperty`:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Another possibility is the use of `java.io.File`:

```
new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

Yet another possibilty uses reflection:

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Comment: Note that this is a bit misleading/confusing. The three methods you quote can give completely different results!

Comment: Zarkonnen: You're right but as implied in my original posting, I'm no expert. This is a community wiki. Please feel free to edit/correct my answer!

Comment: TIP: Usually the path doesn't need to be specified if you want to access a file in the current working directory, like:  file = new File("file.cfg"); Just be sure to always set the working directory to the location of your application during initialization or at the application shortcut.

Comment: @lepe Don’t set the working directory at launch, this has some undesired consequences, such as pointing some file chooser dialogs by default to the application’s path, rather than the user-chosen working directory.

Comment: Two major problems with the last approach:  One, [ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource() can return null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource--).  Two, URL.getPath() does not return a file name, it just returns a (possibly escaped) path portion of a URL.  `C:\Program Files\ExampleApp` is represented in URL form as `file:/C:/Program%20Files/ExampleApp`, for which getPath() returns `"/C:/Program%20Files/ExampleApp"`, which obviously doesn’t exist.  The only correct way to convert a URL to a file is `new File(url.toURI())`.

Answer (score 4):

In **.Net** you can use

`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`

to get the current working directory of the application, and in VB.NET specifically you can use

`My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath`

to get the directory of the exe.

Answer (score 4):

In VB6, you can get the application path using the [`App.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa268072%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) property.

Note that this will not have a trailing `\` EXCEPT when the application is in the root of the drive.

In the IDE:

```
?App.Path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98
```

Answer (score 3):

**Delphi**

In Windows applications:

```
Unit Forms;
path := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
```

In console applications:

Independent of language, the first command line parameter is the fully qualified executable name:

```
Unit System;
path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Libc**
In *nix type environment (also Cygwin in Windows):

```
  #include <unistd.h>

   char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);

   char *getwd(char *buf); //deprecated

   char *get_current_dir_name(void);
```

[See man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getcwd.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

In **bash**, the 'pwd' command returns the current working directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, `pwd` returns the current working directory which may differ from the path of the script.

Comment: The answer is actually found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-in

Answer (score 2):

**Unix**

In unix one can find the path to the executable that was started using the environment variables. It is **not** necessarily an absolute path, so you would need to combine the current working directory (in the shell: `pwd`) and/or PATH variable with the value of the 0'th element of the environment.

The value is limited in unix though, as the executable can for example be called through a symbolic link, and only the initial link is used for the environment variable. In general applications on unix are not very robust if they use this for any interesting thing (such as loading resources). On unix, it is common to use hard-coded locations for things, for example a configuration file in `/etc` where the resource locations are specified.

Answer (score 2):

In **Tcl**

Path of current script:

```
set path [info script]
```

Tcl shell path:

```
set path [info nameofexecutable]
```

If you need the directory of any of these, do:

```
set dir [file dirname $path]
```

Get current (working) directory:

```
set dir [pwd]
```

Answer (score 2):

In **PHP** :

```
<?php
  echo __DIR__; //same as dirname(__FILE__). will return the directory of the running script
  echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; // will return the document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.
  echo getcwd(); //will return the current working directory (it may differ from the current script location).
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

in **Android** its

```
getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
```

to get SD card, I use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type);
```

where the latter is used to store a specific type of file (Audio / Movies etc). You have constants for these strings in Environment class.

Basically, for anything to with app use ApplicationInfo class and for anything to do with data in SD card / External Directory using Environment class.

Docs :
[ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) , 
[Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Java:**

On all systems (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X) works for me only this:

```
public static File getApplicationDir() 
{
    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".");
    File applicationDir = null;
    try {
        applicationDir = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
        applicationDir = new File(url.getPath());
    }

    return applicationDir;
}
```

Comment: This throws NPE if the application is running in a JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

in **Ruby**, the following snippet returns the path of the current source file:

```
path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **CFML** there are two functions for accessing the path of a script:

```
getBaseTemplatePath()
getCurrentTemplatePath()
```

Calling getBaseTemplatePath returns the path of the 'base' script - i.e. the one that was requested by the web server.
Calling getCurrentTemplatePath returns the path of the current script - i.e. the one that is currently executing.

Both paths are absolute and contain the full directory+filename of the script.

To determine just the directory, use the function `getDirectoryFromPath( ... )` on the results.

So, to determine the directory location of an application, you could do:

```
<cfset Application.Paths.Root = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() ) />
```

Inside of the `onApplicationStart` event for your `Application.cfc`

---

To determine the path where the app server running your CFML engine is at, you can access shell commands with cfexecute, so (bearing in mind above discussions on pwd/etc) you can do:

Unix:

```
<cfexecute name="pwd"/>
```

for Windows, create a `pwd.bat` containing text `@cd`, then:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\docume~1\myuser\pwd.bat"/>
```

(Use the `variable` attribute of `cfexecute` to store the value instead of outputting to screen.)

Answer (score 1):

In cmd (the Microsoft command line shell)

You can get the name of the script with %* (may be relative to pwd)

This gets directory of script:

```
set oldpwd=%cd%
cd %0\..
set app_dir=%pwd%
cd %oldpwd%
```

If you find any bugs, which you will. Then please fix or comment.

Answer (score 1):

I released https://github.com/gpakosz/whereami which solves the problem in C and gives you:

- the path to the current executable
- the path to the current module (differs from path to executable when calling from a shared library).

It uses `GetModuleFileNameW` on Windows, parses `/proc/self/maps` on Linux and Android and uses `_NSGetExecutablePath` or `dladdr` on Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Note to answer "20 above regarding Mac OSX only: If a JAR executable is transformed to an "app" via the OSX JAR BUNDLER, then the getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation(); will NOT return the current directory of the app, but will add the internal directory structure of the app to the response. This internal structure of an app is /theCurrentFolderWhereTheAppReside/Contents/Resources/Java/yourfile

Perhaps this is a little bug in Java. Anyway, one must use method one or two to get the correct answer, and both will deliver the correct answer even if the app is started e.g. via a shortcut located in a different folder or on the desktop.

carl

SoundPimp.com