# Getting the absolute path of the executable, using C#?

Tags: c#, directory, executable

Have a look at this pseudocode:

```
string exe_path = system.get_exe_path()
print "This executable is located in " + exe_path
```

If I build the above program and place the executable in `C:/meow/`, It would print out `This executable is located in C:/meow/` each time it is run, regardless of the current working directory.

How could I easily accomplish this using `C#`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218061/get-the-applications-path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[MSDN has an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx) that says to use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`; if you need the directory, use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` on that result.

Or, there's the shorter [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) which "Gets the path for the executable file that started the application, including the executable name" so that might mean it's slightly less reliable depending on how the application was launched.

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() will only get the EXE assembly if that's where it's called from. GetEntryAssembly() will get the correct assembly.

Comment: This is especially important if you create a Windows Service because the service is launched from C:\Windows\System32, so you will have that working directory.  I will use GraemeF's method instead.

Comment: The above mentioned method returns the current path as a URI (i.e. "file://c:\\data"). What worked for was:

`System.Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location ) );`

Comment: It's actually "System.IO.Path".  So fully qualified name with correct namespace should be:  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location )

Comment: I'm unclear after these comments which is the right way! Victor's way doesn't include GetEntryAssembly, which according to @GraemeF would be correct. And what's wrong with Application.ExecutablePath?

Comment: noelicus: according to the answer and the comments, the safe and accurate method that will nearly always work correctly is: System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)

Comment: `Application.ExecutablePath` is part of Windows.Forms, though... which is not referenced by default in console apps.

Comment: The Article is for Compact Framework 1.0.  A little out-dated in my opinion. `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` should be used for the exe.

Comment: This was maybe correct answer in 2009, but for anything but the most basic Windows hello world app correct answer is the one by Liquid Core.

Answer (score 66):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: This is the best, simplest answer.  This method works on linux/mono and Windows, regardless of the current directory.

Answer (score 13):

```
using System.Reflection;

string myExeDir = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).Directory.ToString();
```

Comment: Nice, though it can be simplified to `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`, which is also faster.

Answer (score 8):

```
var dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

I jumped in for the top rated answer and found myself not getting what I expected. I had to read the comments to find what I was looking for.

For that reason I am posting the answer listed in the comments to give it the exposure it deserves.

Comment: Nice, though it should be `.GetEntryAssembly()`, not `.GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Answer (score 4):

"Gets the path or UNC location of the loaded file that contains the manifest."

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx

```
Application.ResourceAssembly.Location
```

Comment: Note that this solution is WPF-specific: "[`Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application) is a class that encapsulates WPF application-specific functionality".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose i have .config file in console app and now am getting like below.

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\YourFolderName\\log4net.config";
```

Comment: CurrentDirectory is not guaranteed to be the directory in which the application is executing.

Comment: Please use `Path.Combine`. There's a lot of code out there that does not properly work in Mono from manually combined paths like this.

Answer (score 2):

On my side, I used, with a form application:

```
String Directory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
```

it takes the application startup path.

Answer (score 2):

The one that worked for me and isn't above was `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to build a console application to be used with Task Scheduler, I'd recommend using this approach:

```
var execDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)?.Replace("file:\\", "");
```

This way, the path will adapt to whatever location you place your executable file in.