# Running C# out of VStudio. XMLWriter

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, release, xmlwriter

I am using XMLWriter to create a XML structure on a ConsoleApplication in C#. When I run it inside VisualStudio works, but the problem comes when I run it from Windows Command (cmd).

I have copied in another directory, but it does not create "numberOfHouses.txt".

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("numberOfHouses.txt", settings);
writer.WriteStartElement("CITY");
writer.WriteElementString("HOUSES","12");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.Close();
```

Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: You probably can't write to the system32 folder where cmd is ran from

Comment: I suppose that this is running in a directory where you don't have permissions

Comment: It doest write the file.

Comment: See Steve's comment or mine, simply don't use hard coded file paths or catch errors

Comment: you can pass in a directory through the program arguments

Comment: Thanks. Hardcoding file path worked!

Comment: @sayse: how can I avoid to hardcode the path? It must be created without specifying the path. it has to be created on the same path where .exe is located

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1658522/1324033)