# How to get path to the projects directory

Tags: c#, directory

For example if I would like to get number of files in the project's directory.
In `Java` I would write:

```
int numberOfFiles = new File(".").listFiles().length;
```

But I do not know how to get path to the project's directory in .NET. How to achieve the same goal in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658518/getting-the-absolute-path-of-the-executable-using-c

Answer (score 2):

It is simple

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's close - use:

```
int numberOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(".").Length
```

Comment: Is there any difference(in the result, effectivness) comparing to John Koerner solution?

Comment: The _result_ should be the same.  You'd have to try it both ways to see if the _performance_ is different.

Comment: Which one would you prefer? I would like to know reference solution -->purist's solution.

Comment: Now that I think about it - the _current directory_ could be different that the _executable path_, so the results _could_ be different if for example, you started the app with a shortcut that set a different startup directory.

Comment: If I run app by a shortcut from desktop the `executable path` or `current directory` will lead to the "real" application directory?

Comment: Yes, unless a different directory is set in the Startup Directory field - that _that_ will be the "current" directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to the executable using [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then get the directory from there.  Once you have the directory, it is easy to get the file count:

```
var executingDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
var numFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(executingDir).Count();
Console.WriteLine(numFiles);
```