# program searching wrong directory for config file when run from task scheduler

Tags: c#, task, filenotfoundexception, path-finding

I have a c# form application.  It opens a text file upon loading.  From this text file it reads the default settings.  It then fills the `numericupdown` fields and `textbox` fields with the default data.

I want to run this every night at a specific time.  The windows task seems to be trying to open the program.  However, upon loading it gets a `FileNotFoundException Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\Settings.txt` Which is nowhere close to my application run folder.  It opens properly when running from command line and using run in MVS2013.

in my program I am searching for this file using relative pathing

could anyone shed some light on this ridiculousness?  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: AFAIK you can set the *working directory* or something with the task ... do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your path is relative to the working directory, which seems to be "C:\Windows\system32" if you didn't specify any. So possible solutions are, set working directory to the directory of your executable file (the "Start in (optional)" field) :

[image]

.. or modify your program to use absolute path of the executable ([you can get the absolute path programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658518/getting-the-absolute-path-of-the-executable-using-c)).

Comment: I am planning to deploy this to customers at some point.  They will all use different directories so absolute pathing is a little out of the question.  However I plan to have a tutorial for them to automate the program.  I will simply instruct them to fill in the working directory.  Thank you!

Comment: Absolute path of the executable determined at run-time according to current location of the exe file. To be clear, the path will change if the executable moved to different directory. So I can't see why it is not an option... Anyway, you're welcome