# File not found exception when running project from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

My C# project needs to read a file that is in the same location as the executable. The file is under `<PROJECT>/bin/x64/Debug/input.txt` and under `<PROJECT>/bin/x64/Release/input.txt`. In the same folders there is also the `program.exe`.

When executing manually the `program.exe` from those directories it reads the file and executes successfully. When trying to run the executable from the visual studio it cannot find the file.

Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658518/getting-the-absolute-path-of-the-executable-using-c) help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code that reads the file.  Also, is there a slash missing in your `Release` path?

Comment: @BACON Thanks. It was actually a spelling mistake while writing the question. I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\input.txt"
```

which returns a string of **"C:\Users\username\source\repos\Solution_name\Project_name\bin\{DEBUG | RELEASE}\input.txt"**

Comment: By default, a relative file path (e.g. `File.OpenRead("input.txt");`) would try to open `input.txt` in the same directory as `program.exe`.  Building an absolute path like this works, of course, but it shouldn't be necessary and there simply isn't enough information provided in the question to know why it would be.  Perhaps the working directory was changed in the project settings.