# Find the location of my application's executable in WPF (C# or vb.net)?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

How can I find the location of my application's executable in WPF (C# or VB.Net)?

I've used this code with windows forms:

```
Application.ExecutablePath.ToString();
```

But with WPF I received this error from Visual Studio:

> System.Window.Application does not contain a definition for ExecutablePath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the application's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218061/get-the-applications-path)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` should work.

Comment: This may not work properly all the times. It will get the executing assembly, not the application's executable. This means this won't work if running through a referenced DLL if you want the application's executable.

Answer (score 40):

Several alternatives:

```
Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Only in VB:

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Comment: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns current directory, not executable location, i.e. when run from outlook (sent as a link to \\server\folder\file.exe it will set BaseDirectory to user documents instead executable location

Answer (score 22):

this is useful for you:
Application.ExecutablePath equals to:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked perfect for me. The alternative - GetExecutingAssembly got me the dll instead of the exe (As mentioned above), and the use of Application.ExecutablePath is not available from where I coded.

Answer (score 14):

The following is applicable in the recent versions of .NET Core:

```
System.Environment.ProcessPath
```

This returns the path of the executable that started the currently running process.

Comment: Why is this answer not being upvoted? This is recommended from a performance standpoint over Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName ( [CA1839](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1839) ). It also correctly returns the location of the exe, not the location of the dll.

Comment: [System.Environment.ProcessPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath) is available in **.NET 6** or later. This is the best way now.

Answer (score 3):

The executing assembly can be a DLL if the code is located in a library:

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); //MyLibrary.dll
var callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); //MyLibrary.dll
var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(); //WpfApp.exe or MyLibrary.dll
```

So the best way I found is (C#) :

```
var wpfAssembly = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .Where(item => item.EntryPoint != null)
                .Select(item => 
                    new {item, applicationType = item.GetType(item.GetName().Name + ".App", false)})
                .Where(a => a.applicationType != null && typeof(System.Windows.Application)
                    .IsAssignableFrom(a.applicationType))
                    .Select(a => a.item))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

So in your case, you can find location of the assembly :

```
var location = wpfAssembly.Location;
```

Comment: Nice technique @scrat789. It gets to the regular .exe's assembly even when running in the debugger. None of that XXX.vshost.exe.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use. It works even in debugger.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static string GetMyBinDirectory()
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
}
```

It uses some powerfull classes, like [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) and [ProcessModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule)

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns parent directory of exe file

Answer (score 0):

Based on others answers, here's an example that shows how to remove the executable name from the path and combine the result with some subfolder and filename:

at my updated version of Hotspotizer (http://github.com/birbilis/Hotspotizer), I've just added support for loading a Gesture Collection file at startup, if found at Library\Default.hsjson, by using the following code:

```
const string GESTURE_COLLECTION_LIBRARY_PATH = "Library"
const string DEFAULT_GESTURE_COLLECTION = "Default.hsjson"

//...

LoadGestureCollection(
  Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
  GESTURE_COLLECTION_LIBRARY_PATH,
  DEFAULT_GESTURE_COLLECTION));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this AppContext.BaseDirectory