# Protection to wpf Application insttaled folder using install shield

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, installation

I am installing an application (via Install Sheild setup) onto a client system, which installs to a particular folder path. This folder contains a few .exe and database files.

My question is:

When I copied the folder (which contains the exe and other files), it should not be copied to any other location in the same system. How can I stop the files from being moved or copied to another location on the same system?

Answer (score 0):

As a developer you have no control on where or how the files are copied as you don't own or manage the file system.

The only thing you can do is come up with a method to determine where the original file was installed (using the installer etc.) and determine if the running application path is the same as the installed path. One way of doing this is by reviewing the InstallDirectory from install shield from the Registry.

Install Sheild Registry Keys:
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/PA_RegistryVariable.htm

WPF Getting Executable Path:
[Find the location of my application's executable in WPF (C# or vb.net)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123870/find-the-location-of-my-applications-executable-in-wpf-c-or-vb-net)

Combining those two techniques should help limit the user from "running" the application from a path that it was not installed to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hkeys Didnot Work Could u please suggest any other solution