# C#-Difference between System.CurrentDomain.AppDomain.BaseDirectory and Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Tags: c#, .net, directory, working-directory

Can anyone tell me what's the difference between `System.CurrentDomain.AppDomain.BaseDirectory` and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in C#, please??

See [AppDomain on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and also [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: As editing is not working: "Hello community" in front of this is missing :/

Comment: [Salutations are not required..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Ok, didn't know about this one.

Comment: "Difference" in what way? They are completely different parts of the API. The values will often, but not always, be the same. The current "working" directory (returned by `GetCurrentDirectory()`) can be changed, either when you start a process or from within. Please explain your question: what difference are you expecting and/or concerned about that isn't already adequately described by the documentation?

Comment: Ok, so then my question would be: "When are those 2 not exactly the same?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123870/find-the-location-of-my-applications-executable-in-wpf-c-or-vb-net) the difference is that

> System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns current
>   directory, not executable location, i.e. when run from outlook (sent
>   as a link to \server\folder\file.exe it will set BaseDirectory to
>   user documents instead executable location
>   from [Jakub Pawlinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813686/jakub-pawlinski) whereas `Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`
>   gets the parent folder of the current execting assembly.

So the code I'm using now is:

```
string location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
if (location != null)
{
    string config = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(location).FullName, "Config.xml"));
}
```