# How to get the full path of the current executable file in VB?

Tags: vb6, path, executable-path

I have created one windows application using VB. Whenever I executing the `exe`, I want to get the current directory of the `exe` file programatically.

For example,

Now, I am executing the `exe` file in `d:\myApp\test.exe`. Whenever I double click the `exe` file I want to get the path of the `exe` file like `d:\myApp\test.exe`.

Also, suppose, my `exe` is in CD or any memory stick, will it also get the path of the exe file?

I don't know is this possible or not?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking about how to [get the path to the executable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11738178/588306), not the current, working directory which is different.

Comment: @Deanna : yes Deanna you are right...i am asking about get the path to the executable... thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try [`App.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa268072%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). It will give you the current `exe` path. To get `exe` name you can use [`App.EXEName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267360%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).
Note that `App.Path` will contain the trailing `\` when in the root of a drive so any extra `\` will need to be added conditionally.

So to get full path with `exe` name try this:

```
App.Path & IIf(Right$(App.Path, 1) <> "\", "\", "") & App.EXEName & ".exe"
```

Also, It will give you CD or any memory stick's path too.

Comment: If you use these in the IDE, you will get the path and the filename (minus the .vbp extension) of the project file.