# Best way to reference the file system in a spring mvc app

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc application, what is the best way to reference the filesystem?

Say I want to know the root of my applications path?

Should I create a properties file and hard code this value in the property file, then create different versions for production and development environments?

I might want to reference a file outside of my application also, so I guess a property file is best suited for this correct?

Comment: That is what I have always used.

Comment: Maybe this can be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218061/get-the-applications-path?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question as a config/release problem, not coding problem. If you want to access file (say with absolute path) there are different ways to achieve it:

- if you use maven to build your app. create **maven profile** with corresponding property, e.g. `file.path` and at build-time fill the property to spring bean (e.g. a String)
- create different **properties files**, which containing config parameters for different environments. and let maven fill the placeholder in spring conf, which properties file should be used.
- use **spring profile**. put server-relevant beans in profiles, and your application choose the right profile (the set of beans) at runtime.
- well if you have different **databases** for different environments, you could consider to save some config parameters in a config table. And application loads those data when it starts or when it needs. At least this is another option.

did that answer your question? or I am just talking about something else?...

Comment: would be nice if you close this answer as "answered"?

Answer (score 0):

Get real path and complete your remaining action

```
String realContextPath =  session.getServletContext().context.getRealPath(request.getContextPath());
```