# Exporting java project from netbeans to executable jar

Tags: java, batch-file, export, executable-jar

Used eclipse in the past fro java coding and didn't have many issues but decided to give netbeans a blast

I'm trying to create a jar file with all dependencies as one jar and yes am familiar with the java-web-start-option and also the jar actually exists in my dist folder once built.

Problem 1

All's good and well, I can launch the jar but seems not without its lib folder which contains: AbsoluteLayout.jar + beanbindings.jars. Something I will need to figure out as I go along.

I call a few batch scripts to complete differenet jobs for me in the java program e.g. one finds memory amounts and displays in a JTextArea. When I use the program within the netbeans ide all works fine.

Problem 2

When I launch the jar file thats in the dist folder it launches just fine but cannot find the batch/bash scripts at all. Below is the path I use within the program which as I mentioned works fine in the IDE and just wondering why it cant find the same path in the jar.

I assumed when I created and built like in eclipe it would make all these commands work in the existing jar in my dist folder (bin in eclipse ofc)?

```
    String[] filepath = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "..\\Enterprise\\src\\enterprise\\batch\\memory.bat"}
```

Any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout.jar`  That is bound to cause problems down the track.  Use standard J2SE (or other 3rd party non-null) layouts for more robust GUIs. *"decided to give netbeans a blast and sorry I did."*  If I wanted to encourage the Netbeans gurus to contribute, that is definitely not something I would mention.  It is not relevant to the problem, and could be quite irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to change your path. Just make a flag if it's in your ide then select this path, if not then use another path. 
Try this link to get the application path in java.

[Get the application's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218061/get-the-applications-path)

Comment: Thanks for both your comments, your link helped me sort the issue nsutgio.  Went with a basic path  [code]String[] filepath = {"C:\\batch\\memory.bat"};[/code] and found netbeans suggested I create the batch folder in question when I closed and re-entered the IDE.