# Relative paths to getResourceAsStream method

Tags: java

I have a jav aproject which is build through ant. It write the class files to output/classes/com/... path. One of my java classes needs input stream read from a file that is in a folder one level above output folder. Looks like if copy the file to the package folder under outptu/classes, it seems to work. But I do not want to palce my config file in output folder as it will be cleaned when I do ant clean. I want it to find it look above the output folder, in config folder and load it.

```
public static final String CONFIG_FILE="/../../../../../../../Config.txt";

public static ConfigObj getConfigObj() throws IOException {

InputStream i=ConfigLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE);
```

...

I want to know when I want to give raltivepath, what should it be relative to. I tried looking up , it says relative to classloader. What is classloader in this case? Is it output/classes/com....../config folder where my ConfigLoader.class lives?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getResourceAsStream()` will only load resources *from the classpath*. I guess you only have `output/classes` on your classpath, so you will never be able to load the config file via `getResourceAsStream()` if it's outside that directory. Use a `File` with an absolut path pointing to the file, or place it in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks so much, zagyi. But absolute paths are not portable, is there no other way I can give path relative to output folder,? adding the directory to classpath does not seem very user friendly.

Comment: If it's really a user configuration file, then I guess users would expect it being placed somewhere under their user home directory according to OS specific conventions. If you do insist to having it relative to your compiled classes, try to use techniques described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/676413/1276804). However I'm not sure about the robustness of such solutions.