# Packaging my project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exe, packaging, executable-jar

I have a Java swing project which i need to test on other computers. I have some classes and a sqlite db which stores login information. I have some lib jars as well. The application takes information from the user and stores it in the sqlite db and then pushes data to the web. I want to package my project so that whoever uses my project has to just double click on an executable or jar.

I tried to Export to a Runnable Jar file in Eclipse but this does not give desired results. After the runnable jar is created and i run it for the first time it creates the sqlite db beside it and does not connect to the web link and send information.

How can i package my data properly?
This is my folder structure -

> root
>       --src
>           ----default package
>           ----rest package
>           ----images
>       --lib
>       --file.fcl
>       --db.sqlite

Comment: You have not given enough information -- you say "does not connect to the web link": does it crash?  Does it give an error message?  Have you created a log file or a console output so that you can see messages that come from the code?  It looks like you can package the project all right -- it runs and creates the database -- so what you have is likely a program bug.  We of SO can help you figure out what a specific bug is, given specific enough information, but we can't do it without information.

Comment: It runs fine in Eclipse without any errors. And after creating the runnable Jar it executes, asks user info, and executes fine in the taskbar. The sqlite db should exist within the jar. It should not create one. Last step of my project is that it pushes a data record into the db of the web app. In this case it doesnt since i can see in my localhost that no record was inserted. :(

Comment: i executed it from cmd and found out that it is not able to read the FCL file. The fcl file is the part of a package that i have used. It throws error - Error reading file 'file.fcl' Cant load file 'file.fcl'

Comment: In your original post you say "...run it for the first time it creates the sqlite db beside it"; in a comment you say "The sqlite db should exist within the jar.  It should not create one.".  So I don't understand which it is, and it doesn't really matter.  I also cannot tell if you want more help -- running it from a command line and getting error output was a good move; now you can look for why your program can (evidently) read "file.fcl" when running in eclipse but not from the jar.  Is there a path to it somewhere?  Did you fail to mark it as a resource that gets included in the jar?

Comment: When i run the Jar file it creates the sqlite db but it should not since i want it to be already there inside the Jar file. I was trying to generate a Runnable Jar file. This does not ask for file inclusion. It just asks for Launch Configuration in which i select the project name and the java file which has the main(). Here is my folder structure                                                                     >root  >src  >default package  >rest package  >images  >lib  >file.fcl  >db.sqlite

Comment: added the folder structure in the question. I also tried to create only a jar instead of a runnable jar. This asks me to include files as well. I included the fcl and the sqlite file but it throws an error in between stating that Resource is out of sync with file system - db.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Any time you run a program outside eclipse that changes any file within a project folder structure, the file changed is "out of sync".  To bring things back in sync, right-click on the project in Package Explorer and choose "Refresh" (you can also select the project in Package Explorer and press F5).

If your code is creating the database instead of using the one that is there, it suggests to me that your database location is set for your eclipse environment but not for the general case.  For a java application, you have to know (or set) the "current directory" or "current folder" -- this is a folder that is the default for file operations, and from which relative file paths are set.  If your current directory is "aaa", and you open a file or database at "bbb/ccc/ddd/database.db", then the "bbb" directory must be within "aaa" or the program won't find the file.

To run your program without having to set the database location, etc., then you're probably going to want to discover the directory in which your program file is stored and set that as your current directory.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218061/get-the-applications-path) indicates how you might do that.

Comment: the db.sqlite and file.fcl are just under the root directory. I opened the jar in winrar and found that both the sqlite file and fcl are missing.